# C# one form instant access controls

Tags: c#, forms, controls

I have the following code that checks if an instant of the form is open. However, I cant access the controls (DataGridView dgvPDF), if the form is already opened:

```
            Form frmPDF = Application.OpenForms["frmPDFs"];
            if (frmPDF != null)
            {
                frmPDF.Focus();
                frmPDF.dgvPDF.DataSource = PDF.CheckPDFs(Files, frmPDF.tblPDFs); <--- red squiggly lines

            }
            else
            {
                frmPDFs frmPDF1 = new frmPDFs();
                frmPDF1.Show();
                frmPDF1.dgvPDF.DataSource = PDF.CheckPDFs(Files, frmPDF1.tblPDFs);
            }
```

The error message was:

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for
>   'dgvPDF' and no extension method 'dgvPDF' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Okay, you've edited it twice, and each edit has a different error. Which one is it?

Comment: Please see latest edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strongly typed variable:

```
Form frmPDF = Application.OpenForms["frmPDFs"];
```

So `frmPDF` is now an instance of type `Form`, which is the *base class* for your form.  It's *not* the type of your actual form.  (It's an instance of your specific form type, but that instance is known to the compiler as its base type in this case.)

What type is your actual form?  Let's assume for a moment it's `Form1`.  Then make it that type:

```
Form1 frmPDF = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["frmPDFs"];
```

Then you can access public members of the type `Form1` on `frmPDF`.

---

**Edit:** According to your comment below, the type is `frmPDFs`.  So use that:

```
frmPDFs frmPDF = (frmPDFs)Application.OpenForms["frmPDFs"];
```

---

**Edit:** Casting might be dangerous, by the way.  You could include some type checking and handle errors more gracefully:

```
frmPDFs frmPDF = Application.OpenForms["frmPDFs"] as frmPDFs
if (frmPDF == null)
{
    // the form was the wrong type, something isn't right
}
```

Comment: How do I find the type of my form. The frmPDF  contains this statement `public partial class frmPDFs : Form`

Comment: @Keylee: According to that code your form is of type `frmPDFs`.  It *inherits* the type `Form`.

Comment: Awesome, it worked!!! With a slight modification `frmPDFs frmPDF = (frmPDFs)Application.OpenForms["frmPDFs"];` I have to wait 2 mins to click  accept answer.

Comment: @Keylee: Glad I could help!  I've added a little more information to the answer regarding type casting as well, just in case you run into issues with that.